# Display won't follow sleep settings, uses disabled screensaver instead

Tags: macos, screensaver

I've been on the Yosemite and noticed only as of just this morning that my screen was on with a screen saver running.

I have screen savers set to **never** start, and I have *Display sleep* set to 10 minutes under Energy Saver.  I went away from my computer again today and came back to find the display on again with the screen saver on again.  I realize I could have processes disrupting display sleep, but why would the screen saver come on if it's been told not to?

Is this some new Yosemite issue?  How might I fix it?

Comment: You could use [caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/). It prevents your computer from going to sleep/displaying screensaver with a tiny applet shown in the top right menu bar.

Comment: I'm not worried about sleep one way or another, but I do want the screen to go dark rather than running a screen saver, which is set to NEVER run.

Comment: Alright then. Will do some research.

Comment: I have a simular problem with Yosemite Server. All Saver/Sleep/EnergySaver is disabled but it still goes to sleep an stops Timemachine Services and kicks users uot from AFP File Sharing. Any ideas? I will test Caffeine tomorrow...
Thanks, Mats Jansson, Sweden

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same effect in full Yosemite installation: screensaver starts when the computer (macbook air) is put down to sleep. If we add to this the battery "eating" behaviour I observed as well. I have unchecked every item that can use power, icloud and handsoff included, but the system itself needs a lot more energy than Mavericks. The general picture of power management seems to be worse than ever.